# What does "Value of type '(CGRect) -> CGRect' has no member 'height'" mean?

Tags: ios, swift

It seems the true cause of the error is I was trying to multiply a Double by a CGFloat. It took me a while to understand this through experimentation and I updated my code to use the equivalent of v3 below, but I still want to understand the error message.

```
class MyView: UIView {
  override public func layoutSubviews() {
    let value: Double = 0.0
    let v2 = value*self.frame.height // Error: Value of type '(CGRect) -> CGRect' has no member 'height'
    let v3 = CGFloat(value)*self.frame.height
  }
}
```

What is this error message trying to tell me?

Comment: I *guess* in case of a type mismatch the getter of the computed property `height` is treated as closure

Answer (score 5):

`self.frame.height` is a `CGFloat`

You have declared `value` as a `Double`

This will work:

```
let v2 = value * Double(self.frame.height)
```

The error message should *probably* read:

```
Value of type '(CGRect) -> CGRect' has no member 'height' of type Double
```

Comment: It should be *Value of type CGRect has no member...*

Comment: It was issue with different type cgfloat and int